# I want to show page when select dropdownlist value

Tags: codeigniter

--Select--
                    admin/order/orderlist/paid" style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none">Paid
                    admin/order/orderlist/successfully"  style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none">Successfully

?>

Comment: Not a very specific question? It is unclear what you are asking about.

Comment: when i select dropdown value i want ot go new page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `:selected` Selector in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ ?

To put it simple, you could do some JS similar to this:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function () {
    var selected = $(this + "option:selected").text();
    if(selected == "someValue")
        window.location = "someUrl";
});​
```

... that is, when someone selects an item, the text of the selected item is grapped using the jQuery selector. Knowing that value you could then decide to which URL you want to sent the user - in this case, by using `window.location`.

The corresponding HTML could look like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>someValue</option>
    <option>someOtherValue</option>
</select>
```